# queue and flow control with delphi using indy

Tags: delphi, queue, indy, priority-queue

i have a client server application (TCP) that's designed with indy delphi.
i want to have a queue and flow control in my server side application.
my server should not lose any clients data when server traffic is full. 
for example , in my server side application i want determine maximum of bandwidth for server is 10Mbps and then if server bandwidth (this 10Mbps) was full the other clients be on queue until bandwidth get free .
so i want to know how can i design this with delphi ?
thanks
best regard

Answer (score 0):

The client should not send the message directly to the server. Put the message in a local store (f.i. sqlite-db) and in a thread you read the first message from the local store and try to send it to the server.

If the message was delivered to the server (no exception raised) delete the message from the local store and process the next "first" message in the local store.

Comment: Hi sir rufo , thanks for reply , well 1 - my application in client side send data to server with a (stream) Tmemorystream or Tstringstream and with a tcpClient.IOHandler.Write command . is there another way  such socket commands or indy instead of using local store or database ? 2 - how can i detemine a max input bandwidth for server ? do you have any examples of your method in delphi ? thanks

Comment: If you do not want to loose any client data then you have to store them somewhere. A **local** store should be available in any case, a remote store or connection may not.

Comment: There is no need to care about the server bandwith. The client can deliver the message or not. The client will get a timeout or not available or whatever exception if not. So you will know, if the message was delivered and if, delete this message from the local store.

Comment: Another option is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx which includes local store and transportation. The base idea is the same: persist to local store, send from local store to server.

Answer (score 0):

Within the TIdTCPServer.OnExecute method which receives the client data, it is possible to 'delay' processing of the incoming request with a simple Sleep command. The client data will stay in the TCP socket until the Sleep command finished.

If your server keeps track of the current 'global' bandwidth usage for all clients, it is possible to set the Sleep time dynamically. You could even set different priorities for different clients.

So you would need a simple but thread safe bandwidth usage monitor, an algorithm which calculates sensible Sleep time values, and a way to assign this Sleep time to the individual client connection contexts.

See also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket
- https://github.com/bandwidth-throttle/token-bucket for an example implementation in PHP
- http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2011/03/tenfold-increase-in-server-throughput.html

Comment: hi dear mjn , thanks for reply .my network have about 7000 users in a mpls network these 7000 clients send data together every morning ... yes in your method before using delay in Tidtcpserver i should have an index before use or not use delay else this delay spend a big time calculate in server side . so this index can be (how much of bandwidth is remain) and if bandwidth was full then try to use sleep command , it seems good , but tell me is there any  way(with indy or others) to determine a max bandwidth for server and calculate how much clients used of that while sending data? thanks

Comment: max bandwidth depends on the hardware (network adapter etc.), for a Delphi way this should be posted as a different question here on SO